# How can I pass an Object from A component to B component in Vue.js without using vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

The two components were defined using vue-router in app.vue as follow:

```html
<div class='app'>
    <div class='nav'>
        <router-link to='/a'>to A component</router-link>
        <router-link to='/b'>to B component</router-link>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>    
</div>
```

---

And I tried to receive an event that contains an object in **app.vue** which was $emit from **A component** and then I could send the object from **app.vue** to **B component**

the code as follow:

```js
    //script in A component
    data () {
       toModify (good) {
         console.log(good)  // {'name': 'mike'}
         this.$emit('tomodify', [good])
       }
    }
```

```html
    <!-- A component -->
    <button class="modifyBtn" @click="toModify(good)">Modify</button>
```

```js
      //script in app.vue
        methods: {
          sendData (good) {
            this.agood = good
            console.log(this.agood)  // undefined
          }
        }
```

```html
      <!--app.vue-->
      <div class="view-wrapper">
        <router-view @tomodify="sendData(good)"></router-view>
      </div>
```

And I don't know why in **app.vue** I can get the event but without the object from **A component**.

Comment: Pass a prop to the parent, and the parent passes props to child

Comment: @pirs Pass a prop to the parent? how? I tried $emit but it doesn't work.

Comment: to be honest, use Vuex, understand the concept and dont waste your time anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official method of passing data from a parent component to a child component is by using [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props). The official method of passing data from a child component to its parent component is by using [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events).

Events are emitted with `this.$emit('event_name', some_data)` in the child component and caught in the parent component's template like `<child-component v-on:event_name="methodName">`.

Comment: Yes, my answer doesn't provide a complete solution, but it contains information for passing from both parent to child and from child to parent. The combination of the two is what will be needed in order to achieve what is desired--that is, first using `emit`, then propagating changes through `props`. I also added an `emit` example specifically because I noticed a comment asking how to get it to work.

Comment: Yes its a good answer, but not a good practice, except for one or 2 props.. very rare

Comment: But how to do if the child-component $emit from the <router-view></router-view> rather than the <child-component> ?

Comment: In the case of your `router-view` component, have you tried just `@tomodify="sendData"`?

Comment: I think I might understand the problem. It looks like you're trying to catch the same `emit` in two separate sibling components. But that's not possible. An `emit` is only available from within the scope of the child making the `emit`. If you want to send the data to `router-view`, you should instead use `props` and pass the data down that way.